# Problem with library dependencies: different libraries depends on different versions of the same library

Tags: angular, npm, webpack, angular-cli

I have several libraries that has a dependency to the webpack library.

Currently, I'm using the version 4.79.1, but when I make `npm install` I receive the following warning:

> karma-webpack@3.0.5 requires a peer of webpack@^2.0.0 || ^3.0.0 but
>   none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

The first thing that came to my mine was to downgrade to the version `3.0.0`, but I started to receive the following warning:

[image]

As you can see, all the libraries present on the warnings depedence of a version equals or grater that `4.0.0`.

What you recomend to do in this kind of situations?

Follows my package dependecies:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^6.1.8",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.1.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.1.8",
    "@angular/core": "^6.1.8",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.1.8",
    "@angular/http": "^6.1.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.1.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.1.8",
    "@angular/router": "^6.1.8",
    "@compodoc/compodoc": "^1.0.0-beta.7",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.8.8",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.79",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "angular2-tinymce": "^2.1.2",
    "codelyzer": "~4.4.4",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "cropperjs": "^1.0.0-rc.2",
    "del": "^2.2.2",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-chmod": "^2.0.0",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
    "gulp-rollup": "^2.15.0",
    "jasmine": "^3.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
    "karma": "^1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
    "karma-html-reporter": "^0.2.7",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-mocha-reporter": "^2.2.5",
    "karma-webpack": "^3.0.5",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^2.0.0-beta.8",
    "ngx-toastr": "8.1.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.2",
    "node-watch": "^0.5.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.0",
    "puppeteer": "^1.7.0",
    "rollup": "^0.49.3",
    "run-sequence": "^1.2.2",
    "rxjs": "^6.3.2",
    "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
    "tsickle": "^0.33.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~2.9.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4",
    "webpack": "^4.19.1"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=6.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.7.3",
    "@angular/cli": "^6.2.3",
    "jasmin": "0.0.2",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.0.0-rc.0"
  }
```

Comment: What version of the karma-webpack do you have?

Comment: @Drag13 I updated my post so you could see all dependecies that I have on my project

Comment: Could you try to switch to karma-webpack 4.0.0-rc.2  with npm i -D karma-webpack@next

Comment: @Drag13 It worked, thank you. Can you put his as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to go with next version of the karma-webpack package with next command:

> npm i -D karma-webpack@next

This will install next (4.0.0-rc.2) version of the karma-webpack.

And don't forget to change version after stable release.